# Error message 'not all code path return a value' appears in a class

Tags: c#

[image: this is the error code I get]

I get this error whenever I open a new class.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Tried returning a value from all the code paths?  Sounds pretty legit of a fix.

Comment: It is possible that neither of your `if` statements resolve to `true` (which would be the case if `this.firstyear` is `false`). If that's the case, you need a final `return <something>;` to ensure that all code paths return a value, as the error states.

Comment: Please enter your code directly in the question as text for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code can be simplified:

```
    public bool CheckStudents(int students)
    {
        if(this.firstyear && students < 150)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Remember, the function returns as soon as the any return statement is hit. You don't need to check for every case, only the cases where you won't return false.